# Ping does not work on fully qualified name on local network

Tags: windows-7, ping

We have a windows 7 Prof 64 bit on our domain network. I was able to connect the web applications on that windows 7 PC via https://PcName.location.company.com/webapp

But now only this URL https://PcName/webapp works

When I issue `ping PcName.location.company.com`

`Ping request could not find host PcName.location.company.com. Please check the name and try again.`

When I issue `ping pcname` it works

ping with  IP Address works

I am using windows XP client

Any idea how i can fix this as this web app is being accessed in another location as well

Thanks

Karthik

**Edit:** Solved this temporarily by adding he ip and FQDN on hosts file on my PC but problem still persists

Comment: Have you tried an `nslookup pcname` and `nslookup pcname.location.company.com`? Make sure they return the same IP address

Comment: nslookup on both does not work says `Non-existent domain`

Comment: Well you've got a DNS problem then, either the server's setup wrong or your client's not pointing at it - it's a simple as that.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check what the machine thinks its FQDN should be with `ipconfig /all`; see the `Primary Dns Suffix` setting.

Comment: It shows the proper location.company.com

Answer (score 0):

Investigate your DNS architecture.

Windows clients by default try to send DNS updates to the DNS server they're pointing at; if it's an AD server with secure updates allowed on that zone, then it should add a record.

Verify that the records are in place - sounds like they're not, and the single-name `ping pcname` is only working because of NetBIOS name resolution.  Allow secure updates on the DNS zone, verify that and AD DNS server is the primary DNS server for these clients, and verify that the network adapter is set to register the address in DNS.